# ProgressDialog on top of Dialogue Fragment

Tags: android, dialog, fragment, progressdialog

I have an activity which displays a Dialogue Fragment when user Performs an action.
when user clicks one button in Dialogue Fragment i want to show a Progress Dialog  but it is shown below Dialogue Fragment,How to bring it to front ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is solved

i am showing progress dialog in transaparent dialogfragment

Answer (score 0):

I think you are showing `Prgress Bar` before `Dialog Fragment` try to show `Progress Bar` just after the `Dialog Fragment`. Hope this will help you

Comment: Can you post your code for showing `Dialog Fragment` and also for showing `Progress Bar`

Comment: DialogFragment newFragment = new Myfragment();
    newFragment.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME,
      R.style.MyDialogTheme);
    //
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");

in Myfragment  i wrote this code,
 progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), null, "Loading...");

Comment: You should update it in your question and also update code for `Dialog Fragment`